# inputFilter for TextInputEditText

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext, android-input-filter

In my application I have an `EditText`.

This `EditText` is for currency input, for example: `2.23`, `9.99`

In other words user can type `2` then `.` then `23` to this `EditText`

To achieve this behavior of `EditText` I implemented an `InputFilter` like in Mussa's answer of this question [EditText with Currency format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627148/edittext-with-currency-format). And it worked like a charm.

But then I wanted to replace my `EditText` by construction like this:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondary_currency"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_currency"
        tools:hint="Болгарский перец">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/secondary_currency_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text="348929.00" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Now, I apply my `InputFilter` to the `TextInputEditText`.

I was surprised when I didn't manage to type `.` after `2`.

Why I can't to type dot in case of `TextInputEditText`? How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current layout code. I can see that you have used `inputType` as `number` and your desirable has to be **decimal**.

You can try with `inputType` as `numberDecimal`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's realy helped

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you cannot setFilter to `TextInputEditText` as it didn't inherit this method from EditText class. I didn't manage t find any similar method in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputEditText.html) for `TextInputEditText`
But you don't have to use specifically ths class with `TextInputLayout`. You can replace `TextInputEditText` with your normal EditText with the filter you had and it'll work as before.

Answer (score 0):

You can add InputFilter to TextInputEditText.

Kotlin

```
secondary_currency_input.editableText.filters[0] = yourInputFilter
```